# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite' import from wsgi.py

Tags: django, django-wsgi

I'm trying to run a python file in a django project and I get this error :
I only get this error on a server and not locally. Locally I did not specify the path.

I'm running the command with : python3 data.py

I have no problem running the django server though.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Spiders.vb_json_cleaner import *
  File "/home/debian/repay-moi/phones/Spiders/vb_json_cleaner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mysite.wsgi import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Here is my wsgi.py file :

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
path = '/home/debian/repay-moi/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And my vb_json_cleaner.py

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'


from mysite.wsgi import *
application = get_wsgi_application()

from phones.models import *
```

Comment: are you using virtualenv,  if its not ativated activate it

Comment: I am in my virtualenv already

Comment: when you getting the error, while starting the server( python manage. runserver)?. or accessing any url. include more details in the question may help it more understandable

Comment: there I added a bit more context. Hope it's enough

Comment: you are running it a python file, instead you need to the run the django application using the command python manage.py runserver( in the virtual env and  change directory to the location of  manage.py file), You need to define the url need to access in the browser in urls.py and write your python codes in views.py file( can also write in other files too).

Comment: If you are not doing a webapplication, django is not needed, run the code to execute in python file and run it,  otherwise define the urls in urls.py file and the python code views.py file ( also read about django apps)

Comment: To run a python code inside a file (data.py)  import it in django's views.py( or in other python modules)